# Building Kino fails at a module, complaining that it's missing, but it's already installed?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, video, video-editing

My system is Fedora 20 KDE x86_64, and here is the "in question" missing module:

```
[root@hostname kino-1.3.4]# yum list libdv
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-free: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: www.fedora.is
 * updates: www.fedora.is
Installed Packages
libdv.i686                          1.0.0-16.fc20                        @fedora  
libdv.x86_64                        1.0.0-16.fc20                        @anaconda
```

I downloaded Kino from here:

```
http://www.kinodv.org/
```

I know the project is dead, but I've heard good things about the software. And it should still do it's job.

Here is the build and error:

```
[root@hostname kino-1.3.4]# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes                             
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B             
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm                     
checking whether ln -s works... yes                                               
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864                  
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes                 
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes                                
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r                      
checking for objdump... objdump                                                   
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all                         
checking for ar... ar                                                             
checking for strip... strip                                                       
checking for ranlib... ranlib                                                     
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok             
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E                                  
checking for ANSI C header files... yes                                           
checking for sys/types.h... yes                                                   
checking for sys/stat.h... yes                                                    
checking for stdlib.h... yes                                                      
checking for string.h... yes                                                      
checking for memory.h... yes                                                      
checking for strings.h... yes                                                     
checking for inttypes.h... yes                                                    
checking for stdint.h... yes                                                      
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.18.4
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for LIBDV... configure: error: Package requirements (libdv >= 0.103) were not met:

No package 'libdv' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBDV_CFLAGS
and LIBDV_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

What is going on here?

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks man, after that I figured it out, I'm at "make" now, and there shouldn't be any problems between now and "make install". I'll add an answer later.

Comment: @jasonwryan How can it be a duplicate if it's not the same error in question?

Comment: @somethingSomething Different error, same problem...

Comment: @jasonwryan I don't know your moderator ways, but those fixes and errors are not the same. My definition on duplicate, is that they are the same and the same fix applies.

Comment: @somethingSomething I'm not a moderator; I just get to cast a vote that others are free to agree, or disagree, with.

Answer (score 0):

As @don_crissti suggested the instructions from [this](http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=298645) thread resolved the issue:

```
yum install libdv-devel
```

then there where a lot of missing dependencies/problems, but kino suggested fixes and using

```
yum whatprovides PACKAGENAMEHERE or COMMAND or MODULE
```

or

```
yum search PACKAGENAMEHERE
```

or

```
yum list PACKAGENAMEHERE
```

solved the remaining errors, except one, and I posted a new [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165791/installing-kino-fails-with-missing-file-linux-videodev-h) for that. (Installing Kino fails with missing file linux/videodev.h)