# Installing Kino fails with missing file linux/videodev.h

Tags: fedora, software-installation, package-management, video, video-editing

I'm running into a brick wall here, I'm getting an error on the command:

```
make
```

in installing Kino(Video Editing Software(Dead Project)).

Here is the error:

```
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/kino-1.3.4/src/kinoplus'
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/kino-1.3.4/src'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall      -I/usr/include/alsa  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -pthread -I/usr/include/libglade-2.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2  -I../ffmpeg -I../ffmpeg/libavformat -I../ffmpeg/libavcodec -I../ffmpeg/libavutil -I../ffmpeg/libswscale -DHAVE_SWSCALE   -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DKINO_PLUGINDIR=\""/usr/local/lib/kino-gtk2"\" -DDATADIR=\""/usr/local/share"\" -D_REENTRANT -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS    -g -O2 -MT kino_common.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/kino_common.Tpo -c -o kino_common.o kino_common.cc
In file included from page_bttv.h:30:0,
                 from kino_common.cc:54:
v4l.h:43:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/videodev.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [kino_common.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/kino-1.3.4/src'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/kino-1.3.4/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/kino-1.3.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Google is giving this error in different cases and one for Kino but no resolve that works for me [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-946708.html) is for ubuntu and didn't work. My distribution is Fedora 20 KDE x86_64. Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem as @don_crissti suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842235/linux-videodev-h-no-such-file-or-directory-opencv-on-ubuntu-11-04) thread, that had the fix.

Excerpt:

```
sudo yum install libv4l-devel
sudo ln -s /usr/include/libv4l1-videodev.h   /usr/include/linux/videodev.h
```

If the link(note this was after trying another solution which was symlinking a file to this same address) exists as it did for me, delete it and run the second command again for symlinking the file.